# How to write multiline Elasticsearch scripts with Postman

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I'm trying to do an Elasticsearch GET query with a very simple script using Postman.  When the script is all on one line it works but if I try to do multiple lines I get an error

I'm sening the data as JSON with Content-Type: application/json in the header

Example - Works:

```
{
    "query":{
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "my_custom_field":{
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "int count = 1; return count;"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example - Produces Error:

```
{
    "query":{
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "my_custom_field":{
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": """
                   int count = 1;
                   return count;
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
 "Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@20493763; line: 9, column: 18]"
```

I think postman may be adding line breaks in behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3):

Triple-quotes in JSON are technically ***not*** valid -- see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json) for more info.

You've essentially got 3 options:

- Write a script which takes in a multiline "JSON" text and produces a `\n`-separated, valid JSON (what I often did before multiline backtick strings were a thing in JavaScript, and still do in php):

```php
function compactifyMultilineString( $input_string )
{
    return str_replace( array( "\r", "\n", "\t" ), " ", $input_string );
}
```

- Use postman's own [pre-request](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/pre-request-scripts/) scripts
- Or, probably the most reasonable option, set up [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/kibana) right next to your ElasticSearch server. Kibana is great for testing out queries and it also supports a postman-ready copy feature:

[image]

Comment: 1st) Your first solution says write a function to parse out linebreaks but where would I be executing that function? Is it somwhere in postman? The point of my question is to be able to write multiline scripts in Postman. 2nd) I looked into Postman's pre-request scripts however this feature doesn't allow you to change the request body, which is what I would need to change because that is where my script is. 3rd) Thanks for this suggestion however I don't have access to Kibana and this seems like more of a work around than a solution that allows me to run multi-line scripts in postman

Comment: Change Postman request body - https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4808

Comment: Then the answer is no. You cannot do that in postman. The investment to get Kibana going is worth it though. What do you use Postman for? JSON payloads to `_search` and other endpoints, no? All of that works in Kibana, plus multiline triple-quote strings, plus autocomplete and much more. Give it a shot.

Comment: Just stumbled on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55954798/8160318